# Most Pythonic was to strip all non-alphanumeric leading characters from string

Tags: python, string, alphanumeric, non-alphanumeric

For example

```
!@#123myname --> myname
!@#yourname!@#123 --> yourname!@#123
```

There are plenty of S.O. examples of "most pythonic ways of removing all alphanumeric characters" but if I want to remove only non-alphabet characters leading up to first alphabet character, what would be the best way to do this?

I can do it with a while loop but im looking for a better python solution

Comment: how did your loop look?

Comment: Do you consider `é` to be alphanumeric? What about `.` as in `1.2`?

Comment: @Blythe, can you match your question title to your question body and add what you consider  *alphabet characters*?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you want to remove leading non-alpha/numeric values:

```
while not s[0].isalnum(): s = s[1:]
```

If you want to remove only leading non-alphabet characters:

```
while not s[0].isalpha(): s = s[1:]
```

Sample:

```
s = '!@#yourname!@#'
while not s[0].isalpha(): s = s[1:]
print(s)
```

Output:

```
yourname!@#
```

Comment: `'1'.isalnum()` -> `True`, `'1'.isalpha()` -> `False`

Comment: @vaultah sorry for the confusion, i edited the question after you answered it. I meant non-alphabet characters, not non-alphanumeric characters. Your answer was correct for the original question, my mistake

Comment: The complexity of this code is awful, with a lot of string copies depending on how many characters are matched. This is not a pythonic way to do this.

Comment: I'm almost afraid to imagine what code would make this solution appear "very elegant" by comparison.

Comment: Sorry guys I cannot delete the answer since it's accepted :), I did what I could :)

Answer (score 10):

Just use `str.lstrip`.

It takes a string containing the characters to remove from the left side of the string, and will remove those characters regardless of the order in which they appear. For example:

```
s = "!@#yourname!@#"
print s.lstrip('@!#') # yourname!@#
```

Comment: this is by far most pythonic answer. Also neet trick if you want to remove all punctuation you can use `s.lstrip(string.punctuation)`

Comment: While this is nice and readable, it may not answer the question as stated. The poster would like to remove all *non-alphanumeric* characters from the start of the string. It is unclear whether it is known that the only non-alphanumeric characters are `!@#` (or in `string.punctuation`, for that matter). A more general solution is to find these first with `leftovers = set(s) - set(string.ascii_letters)`, then strip: `s.lstrip(str(leftovers))`. Though this answer may well be sufficient if `!@#` is all the OP expects.

Answer (score 5):

You could use a regex matching *non-alphanumeric* chars at the start of the string:

```
s = '!@#myname!!'
r = re.compile(r"^\W+") # \W non-alphanumeric at start ^ of string
```

Output:

```
In [28]: r = re.compile(r"^\W+")  
In [29]: r.sub("",'!@#myname')
Out[29]: 'myname'    
In [30]: r.sub("",'!@#yourname!@#')
Out[30]: 'yourname!@#'
```

`\W+` will keep underscores so to just keep letters and digits at the start we can:

```
s = '!@#_myname!!'
r = re.compile(r"^[^A-Za-z0-9]+") 

print(r.sub("",s))
myname!!
```

If you want to just remove up to the first letter:

```
r = re.compile(r"^[^A-Za-z]+")
```

Comment: Hmm doesn't `[^A-Za-z0-9]` perform ASCII-only matching?